# How to check a textbox value when the user press tab

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

The scenario was something like this:

I have 2 textboxes, say txtbox1 and txtbox2. When the user type something on txtbox1 and then press tab, txtbox1 loses focus and txtbox2 got focus. I want to check the value of txtbox1 when it loses focus. If txtbox1 value is invalid, I need to render a `<h:outputText value="Invalid field" rendered=#{bean.errorFlag}/>`

I used `<p:ajax event="blur" />` on txtbox1.

My problem is it doesn't render the outputText even though the value of errorFlag is set to true. I also use update on ajax to update outputText, but it doesn't render it.

Comment: If you are really sure that the flag is set then may be you are not updating the are (probably a `h:panelGroup`) where the `h:outputText` is located. i.e. have you set the value for `update` attribute for `p:ajax`.

Comment: Adan, post the code in some more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the client ID of the to-be-updated element in `update` attribute.

```html
<h:inputText id="input1" value="#{bean.input1}">
    <p:ajax event="blur" update="input1Message" />
</h:inputText>
<h:panelGroup id="input1Message">
    <h:outputText value="Invalid field!" rendered="#{bean.input1Error}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

But... You're basically reinventing JSF validation and not taking benefit of JSF built-in validation API. I strongly recommend to just implement a `Validator` instead.

```
@FacesValidator("input1Validator")
public class Input1Validator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        if (isInvalid(value)) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Invalid field!"));
        }
    }

}
```

and use it as follows

```html
<h:inputText id="input1" value="#{bean.input1}">
    <p:ajax event="blur" update="input1Message" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="input1Message" for="input1" />
```

This keeps your managed bean free from validation and boolean property clutter.

Comment: Thanks BalusC! I just enclosed my outText in a panel group for the update to take effect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use p:tabview. if it is correct, you can use tab change listener

you can look this site 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/tabviewChangeListener.jsf